# How to append a string to a file name in Bash Shell?

Tags: bash, unix, script, rename

So I am supposed to find all the files in the given directory with surffix of .C or cc,
and change their name to .C.blah or .cc.blah

Is there a command to do that?

Or should I implement this with the command find?

Comment: I have actually sorted this out by using the find command, by implementing the -execdir option and mv command, but I still need to play around with it.

Comment: So it will be great if someone can still answer this question with an full answer

Comment: After all the Wiking and googling, I now have the answer to my own question =]

I can use find to execute command on the files returned by find directly.

with the -exec option

so it will be 

    find . -type f \( -name "*.C" -o -name "*.cc" \) -exec mv {} {}.blah\;}

Answer (score 6):

There are a few approaches, depending on what is available on your *nix.

There two different `rename` commands around, one provided through perl, and one as part of standard utils.

Perl version:

```
rename 's/(\.cc$|\.C$)/$1.blah/' *.cc *.C
```

utils version - you might be able to do this with one line:

```
rename .C .C.blah *.C
rename .cc .cc.blah *.cc
```

for loop:

```
for i in *.C *.cc ; do mv $i $i.blah ; done
```

Answer (score 3):

use a simple for-loop:

```
for file in *.txt; do echo $file $file.blah; done
```

This command echoes the old file name and the new file to the terminal. If you're getting expected results, go for the real command:

```
for file in *.txt; do mv $file $file.blah; done
```

Anyway, this won't rename *.txt files in subdirectories. Use find for it.

Answer (score 0):

I know you already found your own acceptable solution, but I want to post what I would normally use at work.  This syntax works for GNU findutils, which is part of any modern linux distro.

```
## xargs is much faster than -exec, xargs can run parallel on # cores with -P #
find ./ -type f -name '*.C' -o -name '*.cc' | xargs -I '{}' mv '{}' '{}'.BAK

##  If I'm specifying more than two extensions, I would generally use a regex
find ./ -type f -regex ".*\.\(C\|cpp\)$" | xargs -I '{}' mv '{}' '{}'.BAK
```

Especially with the now common quad-core SMP servers, you can usually half running time with `-p 4`.  Even with only one core, `xargs` avoids the extraneous forking `find ...-exec` would initiate.  With a desktop, and unlimited time, it's not really a problem.  On the other hand using server resources, and working with many thousands of files, avoiding unnecessary overhead is a priority.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different `rename` commands.

On Ubuntu/Debian/... distros:

```
rename -v 's/$/.blah/' *.C *.cc
```

On RedHat/CentOS/... distros:

```
rename -v $ .blah *.C *.cc
```